# Combine multifile yaml in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, yaml, swagger, swagger-tools

I have my yaml files split up according to a structure like this:

```
.
├── index.yaml
├── info
│   └── index.yaml
├── definitions
│   └── index.yaml
│   └── User.yaml
└── paths
    ├── index.yaml
    ├── bar.yaml
    └── foo.yaml
```

**index.yaml:**

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  $ref: ./info/index.yaml
paths:
  $ref: ./paths/index.yaml
definitions:
  $ref: ./definitions/index.yaml
```

**info/index.yaml:**

```
version: 1.0.0
title: Service API
```

**definitions/index.yaml**

```
User:
  $ref: ./User.yaml
```

**definitions/User.yaml**

```
type: object
properties:
  name:
    type: string
```

...and so on (but you get the idea). I followed the guidance of a [blog post](http://azimi.me/2015/07/16/split-swagger-into-smaller-files.html) that did exactly this. So before calling `initializeMiddleware` from the `swagger-tools` library, my understanding is that I need to merge all these yaml files into a single file. I tried doing that the way [@mohsen____](https://stackoverflow.com/users/650722/mohsen) describes in his blog, leveraging the `json-refs` library and calling the `resolveRefs` (or `resolveRefsAt`) function to get a promise-ified response object that contains a version of the document with the JSON references resolved. This doesn't seem to work though. When I try the following nothing gets logged to the console:

```
let options = {
    filter: ['relative', 'remote']
};

jsonRefs.resolveRefsAt('./swagger/index.yaml', options)
.then(function (res): any {
  console.dir(res);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(res.resolved, null, 2));
}, (err) => {
  console.error(err);
});
```

Comment: @Anthon I modified my question slightly but all the information should be there already. Basically, I have a yaml file that is structured properly. I call `jsonRefs.resolveRefsAt()` on the file and expect to see a log to the console of the file with all the references resolved but I don't see that (and see nothing instead).

Comment: Just FYI, your `index.yaml` is not a valid OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 spec. The blog claims "Swagger spec can use `$ref`s anywhere in the spec" - that's actually [not correct](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues/147#issuecomment-246847871). `$ref` is only allowed in some places - search the [specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md) for `Reference Object` and `$ref` and also see [Reuse Philosophy](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/guidelines/REUSE.md).

Comment: When `$ref`s are used correctly, tools like Swagger UI can/should be able to resolve the references in the main file automatically, without having to merge the files.

Comment: @Helen OK this is great. Sounds like the error is with my use of `$ref`s and not my use of the `json-refs` library. That being said, that was what I first looked at (to see if my structure was incorrect in some way), and I was unable to find anything that looked like I was misusing the `$ref` tag

Comment: @Helen Missed your inclusion of the Reuse Philosophy the first time I read through that. I think that will definitely help me find my problem Thanks very much, will post back if I still can't find it.

Comment: Here's an example that shows almost all allowed usages of external `$ref`s: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v2.0/yaml/petstore-separate/spec/swagger.yaml

Comment: @Helen what function exactly is dereferencing all these relative paths? Currently I call `yaml.safeLoad(fs.readFileSync(swaggerPath, 'utf8'));` and pass that into `swagger.initializeMiddleware(swaggerDefinition, (middleware) => {});`

Comment: I'm not familiar with swagger-tools, sorry. This is usually handled by a tool's Swagger parser, e.g. in the [Swagger Editor](http://editor.swagger.io) this is done by [swagger-js](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-js).